# Animate icon during data loading and transint it to the static state with animation when loading finished

Tags: android, kotlin, animation

How implement animation with the next behaviour:

1. When data is being loading icon should be animated like a pendulum (-15 to 15 degree)
2. When data was loaded icon should be changed to another one with alpha channel animation, namely:

Loading state:

```
Animation 
{
ImageView: icon1
from: -15 degrees to 15 degrees
}
```

Loaded state:

```
Animation
{
ImageView: icon1 -> icon2
from: -15 degrees to 15 degrees to 0 degrees
alpha: icon1 (1.0 to 0.0) -> icon2 (0.0 to 1.0)
}
```

Note: I wrote animation for the first case:

```
    <rotate
        android:repeatCount="infinite"
        android:repeatMode="reverse"
        android:fromDegrees="-15"
        android:toDegrees="15"
        android:pivotX="50%"
        android:pivotY="100%" />
```

But I do not know how to implement the second one with smooth transition.

Answer (score 0):

I discovered MotionLayout. It has animations and states. I resolved my problem.